# Altova Mapforce: Can it create all elements in the output XSD?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xsd, altova

Good Afternoon Developers,

Just a quick question (I hope!)

I am creating an XSLT file through Altova Mapforce and I was wondering if anyone knows whether it is possible to specify that the XSLT stipulates to create all elements and nodes in the Output XSD file even if there is no Input stipulated from the Input XSD?

I know that I can add the extra code to the XSLT myself to add the empty elements but before I commit myself to the task I wondered whether it may be built in to do this itself.

Many Thanks All,

Louis Russell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any more information on this being a possibility so I am creating any missing elements and nodes before the Xml is passed into the XSLT.

Many Thanks to all who looked.